# You Tell Me What To Choose

Tags: no-computers, chess

I found this nice problem in A.C. White’s 1912 book “The Theory Of Pawn Promotion” the other day. Enjoy!

It’s White to move and checkmate Black in 5 moves, Don’t forget to explain the title!

**Wolfgang Pauly, Münchner Neueste Nachrichten 1909**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's

> 1. d7

which starts it. Then black can do one of the following 
First

> 1... e3 2. d8(R) and followed by either 2... h3 3. Rd3 b6  or 2... b6 3. Rd3 h3.  They end up in the same position and then 4. Rc3 forces either 4... Rxc2 5.Rxc2# or 4... Rxb3 5. Rxb3#

Second

> 1... h3 2. d8(B) and followed by either 2... e3 3. Bh4 b6  or 2... b6 3. Bh4 e3.  They end up in the same position and then 4. Be1 forces either 4... Nd2 5.Bxd2# or 4... Nc3 5. Bxc3#

and Finally

> 1... b6 2. d8(N) and followed by either 2... h3 3. Nc6 e3  or 2... b6 3. Nc6 h3.  They end up in the same position and then 4. Nd4 forces either 4... Rxc2 5.Nxc2# or 4... Rxb3 5. Nxb3#

The title refers to

> based on blacks first move, white chooses a different piece to promote to.